# The event.preventDefault is not working

Tags: php

I have this codes below and I can't get the event.preventDefault() working. The thing is, I already have other form and it worked well.
I'm sure you guys can help me out.
Here are the codes:

```
$(document).on('dblclick','td.selecionaCodigoCliente', function(){
            //event.preventDefault();
            $("#mostraClienteSelecionado").html("Cliente [" + this.parentNode.children[0].innerText + "]: " + this.parentNode.children[1].innerText);
            $('input[name="salvaCodigoCliente"]').attr('value',this.parentNode.children[0].innerText);
        });
```

PS: this code above is for the dblclick in a table.

```
$("#botaoSalvaOS").on('submit',function(event){
        $.post("salvaOS.php", $(this).serialize(),function(){
            $("#sucessoOS").html("Dados inseridos com sucesso");
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    })
```

PS: this cobe is for handle the submit

When I submit the form, I get the PHP response. This is the PHP code.

```
<?php
    include_once('db.php');

    $dataAberturaOS = date('d-m-Y');

    $codigoCliente = $_POST['salvaCodigoCliente'];
    $equipamento = $_POST['equipamento'];
    $marca = $_POST['marca'];
    $modelo = $_POST['modelo'];
    $nserie = $_POST['nserie'];
    $acessorio = $_POST['acessorio'];
    $observacao = $_POST['observacao'];
    $defeitos = $_POST['defeitos'];

    if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO ordemdeservico VALUES('NULL', '$equipamento', '$marca', '$modelo', '$nserie', '$observacao', '$acessorio', '$defeitos', '$codigoCliente', '$dataAberturaOS', '$dataAberturaOS', 'ABERTA')"))
        echo "Successfully Inserted";
    else
        echo "Insertion Failed";
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: move event.preventDefault();before $.post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct. Maybe Abhik Chakraborty comment may help. You can also try to add a `event.stopPropagation();` to avoid event bubbling up to a different handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning false instead:

```
$("#botaoSalvaOS").on('submit',function(event){
    $.post("salvaOS.php", $(this).serialize(),function(){
        $("#sucessoOS").html("Dados inseridos com sucesso");
    });
    return false;
})
```